# Wordpress syntax error on live host, working fine on local

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax, host

I've been working on a wordpress project for the past few days on my localhost.
When I was done with it, I tried uploading it on my live host.
But when the installation was finished, it showed a syntax error, saying "**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in ...**"

The code is the following :

```
function Consulin_header_style() {  
if (Consulin_meta('enable_custom_header_style') == 1):
    $images = Consulin_decode(Consulin_meta( 'header_image'));
    $header_images = '.page-title { background-image: url('. wp_get_attachment_image_src($images[0],'flat-page-title')[0].');}';
else:       
    if ( get_header_image() != "" ) {
        $header_images = '.page-title { background-image: url('. get_header_image().');}';  
    } else {
        $header_images = '.page-title { background-image: url('.CONSULIN_LINK.'images/page-title.jpg) ; }';
    }
endif;
wp_add_inline_style( 'Consulin-style', $header_images );
}
```

The 4th line of the code which says "**$header_images = ...**" is the problem.
I have absolute zero knowledge of programming, so I'd appreciate some help here.

P.S: It works perfectly fine on localhost.

Comment: make sure you are using the same php version you used in your localhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment states, this error is related to *php* versions. You have an older *php* version in your production environment.
Still, to make your code backwards compatible, you could change your code to something like this:

```
// …
if (Consulin_meta('enable_custom_header_style') == 1):
    $images = Consulin_decode(Consulin_meta( 'header_image'));
    $imageData = wp_get_attachment_image_src($images[0],'flat-page-title');
    $header_images = '.page-title { background-image: url('. $imageData[0].');}';
else:
// …
```

Explanation:
In older versions of *php* you could not use the return value of a function directly. The solution above stores the return value in a temporary variable, and using that when referencing its `[0]` index.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly fine. Both the code you suggested, and upgrading the PHP version worked fine.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.